# Scala: Get element of a list with with two restrictions

Tags: scala, list

I have a list of type `Example` with the following elements:

```
Example("One", "1", null)
Example("Two", "1", null)
Example("Three", "2", someObject)
Example("Four", "3", someObject)
Example("Five", "3", null)
Example("Six", "3", someObject)
Example("Seven", "4", someObject)
```

I want to get the first element that has `null` in the third field and `"3"` in the second field.

In this specific case it would be the entry with `"Five"` in the first field.

How can I do that? What would be the best functional approach to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `List.collect` method with pattern matching:

```
list.collect{ case Example(x, "3", null) => x }
// res1: List[String] = List(Five)
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: `find` or `collectFirst` would be more efficient in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
list.find(elem => elem._3 == null && elem._2 == "3")
```

or

```
list.find { 
  case Example(_, "3", null) => true 
  case _ => false
}
```

the 1st solution is a bit ugly, but if you are doing something very simple/small it avoids the extra code of the 2nd (IMHO)